# Is there any Javascript function that can redirect to another HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, redirect, hyperlink

I gave an example of what I'm trying to do. Can it be done in any way?

```js
function ClosingHTML(){
    DoSomeClosingCSSTransition();
    setTimeout(function() {
        SendMeToAnotherHMTL();
    }, 2000);
}
```

```html
<div onClick='ClosingHTML()'></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> you can use

```
window.location = 'your link'; in javascript
```

Answer (score 2):

Just set the [window location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location):

```
function ClosingHTML(){
    DoSomeClosingCSSTransition();
    setTimeout(function() {
        window.location = '/some/other/page.html';
    }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: i think he wants to stay on the page

Comment: @FinciucSergiu No way to tell that from what he's said.

Comment: Sounds more like he wants to redirect to a new HTML sheet/page.